# Prod issue: "Unknown entity type: productsearch."

Tags: orocommerce

I'm experiencing a prod issue with one of the clients. This error happens when the customer is adding a product with up-sell products to the cart. Instead of showing a popup with add-to-cart notification and list of up-sell products, the error "Unknown entity type: productsearch." is pushed to console.The biggest problem is that error exists only on PROD. It's not reproducible neither on staging env nor locally. Clearing caches didn't help. I believe it's happening in this piece of code in `Oro\Bundle\ApiBundle\Batch\Processor\UpdateItem\NormalizeEntityClass`:

```
public function process(ContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var BatchUpdateItemContext $context */

    $entityClass = $context->getClassName();
    if (!$entityClass || false !== strpos($entityClass, '\\')) {
        // an entity class does not exist in the context or it is already normalized
        return;
    }

    $normalizedEntityClass = $this->getEntityClass(
        $entityClass,
        $context->getVersion(),
        $context->getRequestType()
    );
    if (null !== $normalizedEntityClass) {
        $context->setClassName($normalizedEntityClass);
    } else {
        $context->setClassName(null);
        $context->addError(
            Error::createValidationError(
                Constraint::ENTITY_TYPE,
                sprintf('Unknown entity type: %s.', $entityClass)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

But can't understand where to move from here. Would be happy to hear any ideas as the issue is quite critical.

We installed XDebug on platform.sh, but there's nothing in the logs about the error. Looking into debugging it looks like the 'productsearch' api model is not being loaded into the entity alias cache for some reason. It's odd that error persist only on PROD website. Here're some screens from debugging:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share the log of this error with the stack trace. To find what caused an issue, we need to know what request was done and what code was run to handle the request

Comment: Hi @AndreyYatsenko. Thanks for your reply. We couldn't get any error info in trace stacks. Please, see screenshots above. Hope they might help in understanding the error source.

Comment: Hi again Greg. We've checked the screenshots, and it's hard to say what is wrong, you have to debug it further to understand why the alias is not loaded here

Comment: Hi again Andrey. I think we moved a bit further and found out that prod vs local uses different types of cache for some reason when loaded in Oro\Bundle\ApiBundle\Provider\ConfigCache: plain vs frontend. It's probably the can't find 'productsearch' api model in plain cache as it's not there. But have no idea why it's may happen.
I created a support ticket on Oro Partners portal and shared it with you. Would highly appreciate any help, as I'm really out of ideas.